# Javascript weird error when trying to load a worker on localhost

Tags: javascript, worker

Trying to run this in a default XAMPP installation under Windows XP using Firefox 7.0.1.

Those codes:

```
var worker = new Worker("c:/xampp/htdocs/js/worker.js");
var worker = new Worker("c:/127.0.0.1/js/worker.js");
var worker = new Worker("c:/192.168.1.2/js/worker.js");
var worker = new Worker("worker.js");
```

Generates those errors:

```
Failed to load script: c:/xampp/htdocs/js/worker.js (nsresult = 0x805e0006)
Failed to load script: c:/127.0.0.1/js/worker.js (nsresult = 0x805303f4)
Failed to load script: c:/192.168.1.2/js/worker.js (nsresult = 0x805303f4)
Script file not found: worker.js
```

Maybe related: had problems with this router, for instance, I can't access my site using http://www.mydomain.com/, I have to access it using http://192.168.1.2/ .

Answer (score 3):

You can't load scripts from your hard drive.

You need to reference files using relative or absolute paths on the server.

Comment: I don't know about 2011, but it's false: you CAN load Workers from the hard drive. The problem is you either need to use relative paths or to use the `file:` protocol. Also it falls in the same restrictions as XHR, so in Chrome both are blocked, in Internet Explorer there is a prompt and in Firefox it's allowed.

Comment: @GustavoRodrigues: He said he's using XAMPP.  If your page is coming from a server, you can't.

Comment: Oh, I didn't noticed that, sorry, mistake of mine.